# Initial download of data in firebase on child_changed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

When using the following method

`firebaseDb.child('somechile').on('child_changed', cb)`

I noticed by watching the frames of the web socket connections in developer tools (chrome) in Network tab, web sockets (WS), that the firebase sdk downloads the whole data set exists in 'somechild' at the time of starting the listener (not only changes).

Is this a correct behavior? 
I was expecting to see only the changes to the data set exists in "somechild" (i.e., nothing at the time of starting the listener) .

Any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

That is indeed the expected behavior.

On the wire, you're simply watching `firebaseDb.child('somechile')`.  Concepts like `child_added`, `child_changed`, or `value`, are client-side implementation on top of that.

Comment: That means if I am watching the child_changed on 'somechild' node, I am downloading all data in 'somechild' at beginning?; 
I am just trying to implement a scroll live pagination and wanted to 
0- use `once(value)` to get data of each page. 
1- monitor child_change, child_remove on the whole 'somechild'
2- monitor child_Add on limitTolast(1)

Then, this strategy would not be helpful.